# LINQ - SelectMany from multiple properties in same object

Tags: c#, linq

Assume you have the following simple objects:

```
 class Order
{
    public Customer[] Customers { get; set; }
}

class Customer
{
    public SaleLine[] SaleLines { get; set; }
}

class SaleLine
{
    public Tax[] MerchTax { get; set; }
    public Tax[] ShipTax { get; set; }
}

class Tax
{
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

With these objects, I want to be able to get a list of all the unique tax rates used on the entire order, including both merchandise and shipping tax rates.

The following LINQ query will get me the list I need, but only for merchandise taxes:

```
            var TaxRates = MyOrder.Customers
            .SelectMany(customer => customer.SaleLines)
            .SelectMany(saleline => saleline.MerchTax)
            .GroupBy(tax => tax.Rate)
            .Select(tax => tax.First().Rate
```

How can I get a list that contains list of unique tax rates that contains both merchandise and shipping rates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
var TaxRates = MyOrder.Customers
            .SelectMany(customer => customer.SaleLines)
            .SelectMany(saleline => saleline.MerchTax.Concat(saleline.ShipTax))
            .GroupBy(tax => tax.Rate)
            .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Basically the change is the call to `Concat` which will concatenate two sequences together.

Comment: You can change the last `Select` projection to `Select(tax => tax.Key)`.

Comment: Follow-up question, and I can add this in a new question if needed. Both tax types can be null. What do I do when merch tax has a value, but ship tax is null? I can add a .where clause before the select many, but the concat would still try to concat both.

Comment: @AaronS: If this is within LINQ to Objects, I'd probably write my own `NullToEmpty` extension method, which returns either the existing value or an empty array if necessary. Alternatively, just make sure the arrays are never null - make sure they're empty arrays instead. That's generally a good idea to start with, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used like this;

```
var TaxRates = MyOrder.Customers
        .ToList()
        .SelectMany(x => new[] { x.SaleLines, x.MerchTax })
        .GroupBy(tax => tax.Rate)
        .Select(group => group.Key);
```